# How efficient is storing Points as Object in Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

In my app I need to store thousands of points (x,y), the points can be grouped by building where each building can have hundreds of points. I have 2 options:
1.Make a location table that have 2 fields, point and its building.
2.Store the building points in the building tables as a json file (that to be parsed manually - I have no problem parsing json).

Which is better in terms of performance, I am afraid that the first solution may have performance impact as the location table can be very huge (hundred of thousands of records) and queries may be slow.

What do you think?

Comment: don't really understand "2 files, point and its fielding", but I can say that thousands of points which will typically be read, written and transmitted as a group will work far better as a file (JSON formatted or otherwise) than thousands of individual rows in a parse table.  As a question, this is slightly out of scope for SO, which would rather have you develop a solution and ask here about a specific programming problem.

Comment: I fixed the typo (sometimes autocorrection is a curse).
I got your point. But doesn't parse already do smart indexing and I imagine that they do clustering of rows by the building. so actually they should be stored in one file (or so) in the underlaying database?

Comment: I see.  You might be right that mongodb confers some advantages that improve the individual rows idea.  This is the kind of thing that's better found out through experimentation.  If you do an experiment, I'd be curious to see the result.